# Is it a better practice to create Conda Environments in the default directory or within each individual project's directory?

Tags: python, conda

If I use a different environment for each project, is it a better practice to store my Conda envs within the same default directory or have each env stored within its project directory? It doesn't seem to matter either way right now (since I have very few projects and none are very complex), but will it at some point in the future?

Comment: Assuming your projects use source control, it would be normal practice to have multiple copies of your project scattered around why different bits of code are experimented wtih. I think you'd create conda environments in some development directory and check the projects out into them. Very much just one person's opinion!

Comment: It doesn't matter all that much. For me what matters more is keeping a YAML definition of the environment under version control (e.g., capture a `conda env export` every time a change is made to the environment). This can be done no matter where the env is. If you want to use the env for other projects, then centralizing in the `envs_dirs` makes sense; if you want to isolate so it's hard to use in other projects, then put in the project (but still only version control the YAML).